# Alter a string with different types of elements

Tags: python

A string has different types of elements such as strings, integers, and floats.  I have to change certain elements but not others.
String changes to all lower case, and integers change to negative. Floats stay the same.

I've tried a few things and they haven't worked at all. This code isn't even close but I figured I show something.

```
newint = []
for i in input:
        if type(i) in input == str:
            i.lower()
            return i
        elif type(i) in input == int:
            newint = i * -1
            return i

if input = ["Hello",  33, 3.14, "Joe", -2] at the beginning,
        then at the end input=["hello", -33, 3.14, "joe",  2]
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow please check https://stackoverflow.com/conduct . If you want some help please define what you are trying to achieve with some examples. it will be a lot easier to get an answer then

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
input = ["Hello", 33, 3.14, "Joe", -2]

for i in range(0, len(input)):
    if type(input[i]) is int:
        input[i]=-input[i]
    if type(input[i]) is str:
        input[i]=input[i].lower()
print input
```

you have to use index to access and replace in the input list `for i in input:` will not get the job done.

Have a look at [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to explain in simple words:

```
input_items =  ["Hello", 33, 3.14, "Joe", -2]
output_items = []

for item in input_items:
    if "int" in str(type(item)): # Check for integers
        if item < 0: # Check if number is negative
            item_int = item * -1 # Multiply by -1
            output_items.append(item_int)
        else: # Item is positive
            output_items.append(item)

    elif "float" in str(type(item)): # Check for floats
        output_items.append(item)

    elif "str" in str(type(item)): # Check for string
        item_lower_case = item.lower()
        output_items.append(item_lower_case)

    else: # Some other data type, just add it to output
        output_items.append(item)



print(output_items)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I did not realize I had to use each check each one by name.

Comment: No problem!  : )